# nested field update in mongo (update inside update query)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Using below query am able to set **status.id, status.name** based on a condition. But at the same time I need to update milestone completedDate for a particular milestone in milestone array where its milestoneID is -1 on the same documents.

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({ formData: { $elemMatch: { value: todayDate } } }, { $set: { 'status.id': -1, 'status.name': 'Closed' } }, { multi: true }, function (err, result) {

});
```

a sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7defd5cb90e73710d0a9de"),
    "status" : {
        "id" : NumberInt("-2"),
        "name" : "SR_EXECUTION STARTED"
    },
    "milestone" : [
        {
            "milestoneID" : NumberInt("-1"),
            "completedDate": ????
        },
        {
            "milestoneID" : NumberInt("0")
            "currentMilestone" : false
        },
        {
            "milestoneID" : NumberInt("-2"),
            "currentMilestone" : false
        }
    ],
    "cost" : NumberInt("0"),
    "formData" : [
        {
            "label" : "Name",
            "value" : "Test"
        },
        {
            "label" : "Description",
            "value" : "test"
        },
        {
            "label" : "Start Date",
            "value" : "2020-Mar-27"
        },
        {
            "label" : "End Date",
            "value" : "2020-Apr-30"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can try this approach to update specific sub-document within an array based on a condition: [Update Specific Elements of an Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents).

Comment: @prasad how to do it???

Comment: There are examples in the linked documentation. Please try that, and post any difficulty you face. Also, do a search on updating nested documents in an array.